# Errors running Meteor app in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: node.js, typescript, meteor, ecmascript-5

I am trying to get my Meteor/Typescript app to run in Internet Explorer 11 (ES5).

I get a blank page and a lot of errors in the console, all in the Meteor packages (`modules`, `babel-runtime`, `promise`, `fetch`, `dynamic-import` etc):

[image]

Here are my meteor packages:

```
meteor-base@1.4.0
mobile-experience@1.0.5
mongo@1.7.0            
reactive-var@1.0.11    
tracker@1.2.0          
standard-minifier-js@2.5.0
es5-shim@4.8.0            
ecmascript@0.13.0         
shell-server@0.4.0        
react-meteor-data
check@1.3.1
meteortesting:mocha@1.0.0
dburles:factory
hwillson:stub-collections
momentjs:moment
promise@0.11.2
jquery@1.11.11
templating
email@1.2.3
deanius:promise
xolvio:email-stub
fourseven:scss
http@1.4.2
seba:minifiers-autoprefixer
alanning:roles
underscore@1.0.10
force-ssl@1.1.0
msavin:mongol
aldeed:collection2@3.0.0
adornis:typescript
apollo
swydo:graphql
swydo:ddp-apollo
```

and my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2019",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "imports/types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.jest.*", ".meteor", "node_modules/**"]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `meteor reset && rm -rf node_modules && meteor npm install`?

Comment: Does it run in other browsers ok? Have you tried Edge?

Comment: It works fine in modern browsers. Same errors with Edge.